# Requesting access token to Zoom API via Oauth - error 'missing grant type'

Tags: json, oauth, axios, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to receive an access token from the Zoom api via Oauth. No matter what form I try and send the body as, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' or Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it always errors to { reason: 'Missing grant type', error: 'invalid_request' }.

```
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://zoom.us/oauth/token",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: process.env.AUTH_CODE,
  }),
  redirect_uri: "https://zoom.us",
};

var header = {
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      "Basic " +
      Buffer.from(process.env.ID + ":" + process.env.SECRET).toString("base64"),
  },
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

var tokCall = () =>
  axios
    .post("https://zoom.us/oauth/token", options, header)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });

tokCall();
```

I'm fairly certain the answer lies in either the data type in which Oauth is receiving the data, or where/if it's receiving the body at all. Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 6):

The error is being thrown because you're sending the data as the body of the post request when the `Request Access Token Zoom API` is expecting to find them as query parameters which you might know as query strings.

**Reference**

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth#local-test

[Image of page from link to highlight the use of query parameters and content-type requirement for API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU8PP.png)

Change

```
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://zoom.us/oauth/token",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: process.env.AUTH_CODE,
  }),
  redirect_uri: "https://zoom.us",
};
```

to

```
var options = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://zoom.us/oauth/token",
      params: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: process.env.AUTH_CODE,
        redirect_uri: "<must match redirect uri used during the app setup on zoom>"
      },
    };
```

The `Content-Type` header should be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as this is a requirement of the zoom API itself.

BTW, *axios* requires you to name the body field/object of your request as data and also there's no need for `JSON.stringify()` method since *axios* does that for you under-the-hood

Comment: This answer is correct however the current zoom documentation is misleading
https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth/#getting-an-access-token
See this screenshot https://imgur.com/FXsQtCw

Comment: I think that is more than just "misleading"... its a direct contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a late answer, I'd like to share it since it took me some time to complete this using Axios.
So to make Zoom authorization, you need to do:

1. Base64 encode the secret and client id

```
const base64EncodedBody = 
 Buffer.from(`${ZOOM_CLIENT_ID}:${ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString('base64');
```

2. URI encode the grant_type, code and redirect_uri

```
const data = 
 encodeURI(`grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`);
```

3. Send the request

```
    const response = await axios.post('https://zoom.us/oauth/token', data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${base64EncodedBody}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
      },
    });
```